# PHP multiple values in strtotime do not work together

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to get multiple values is strtotime to work together but they will not so I may be missing something or in need of a work around.

For example

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 month first saturday'));?>
```

In this example you will get the date in 2 months but the day of week will be consistent with the day of week for this saturday not saturday in 2 months.

EDIT

This code from BUTTERBROT `strtotime("first saturday", strtotime("+2 month"));` solves the immeidiate problem however now when it looks for the first saturday in APRIL and JULY of this year it displays the 9th instead of the 2nd. Does anyone know why and how to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime takes a secound argument as optional timestamp, maybe you can chain the function so they get called in the correct order:

```
strtotime("first saturday", strtotime("+2 month"));
```

Comment: Thats's done it but I have noticed a problem with it. If we take for example the month of April this year or July. For both the first saturday is the 2nd. Yet it believes that should be the 9th. Any ideas why

Comment: yes this bit wierd, maybe this here works out for you $saturday = strtotime("first saturday", strtotime("+2 month", strtotime(date("01-m-Y"))));

Answer (score 0):

"first saturday +2 months" works for me

edit:
I think your problem is you use "month" instead of "months"

Comment: Well for me it is giving 2011-04-05 when it should give 2011-04-02